# jk_mod and apache rewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, glassfish, mod-jk

Is it possible to combine rewrite rules with jk_mod with server side forward?

I have a simple configuration

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/$ /myapp [R]

JkMount /* worker_1
```

This works great when using the redirect flag but fails to run without it. What I want to achieve is a server side forward so the user's browser bar doesn't notice the rewrite.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you need to get `www.example.com/somepage` to map to `www.example.com/myapp/somepage` but still show `www.example.com/somepage` in address bar? Do you absolutely need mod_jk or are you open to use mod_proxy_http?

Comment: Yes this is exactly the behaviour I need. We use Glassfish with mod_jk, don't know if mod_proxy_http would do the job for us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give a try to mod_proxy_http, You need to enable mod_proxy and mod_proxy_http:

```
LoadModule proxy_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_proxy_http.so
```

Then in your VirtualHost section:

```
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass /css !
ProxyPass /img !
ProxyPass /js !
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/myapp/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/myapp/
```

Note: the `ProxyPass /xxx !` are not needed from your question. I just wanted to show how to exclude some URI from being 'translated'

Comment: Thanks, I will try and report back.